# How to get window title of a program reduced in taskar?

Tags: c#, windows, process, taskbar

With C#, i use this code to list main window processes titles

```
Process[] ProcessArray = Process.GetProcesses();
try {
    foreach (Process proc in ProcessArray) {
        Console.WriteLine(proc.MainWindowTitle);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

but this doesn't work to see mainwindowtitle of processes reduced in the taskbar.
How to do this ?

Comment: Are you referring to programs that have been minimized or a program whose icon shows in the system tray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the processes you can probably use the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498(VS.85).aspx) api function through the P/Invoke layer.

Once you have the window handles, you can call the [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx) to get the title of the window.

Comment: My creepy code sample to demonstrate how it works :-)
http://pastebin.com/b8pu1VWv